# What is the rarity of unique weapons in shadow fight 3?

Tags: shadow-fight-3

http://shadowfight.wikia.com/wiki/Weapon_(SF3)

This one says that items can be common, rare, epic, or legendary

However, during festivals, we are supposedly use "rare" items.

Festivals allow us to buy "unique" items.

Which one has higher rarity? Unique or legendary items?

Answer (score 2):

Of course legendary items has the highest rarity and I have verified it myself. Some of the reasons are:

1. During events the legendary weapons have more rarity.
2. Legendary weapons have better set bonuses.
3. Legendary take more shadow energy to upgrade.

So Legendary has the highest rarity in terms of power in game but you would only get unique items once.

*Conclusion:* **Legendary** items has *more* rarity than **unique** items.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure they are equal since both of them have the same amount of slots for abilities.

Comment: no source? I will wait for more credible answer. It does look equal to me.

Answer (score 1):

No , unique rarity equipments are much stronger than the equipments of legendary rarity. Epic rarity equipments also have three slots. Besides , there are few equipments which has two slots instead of three. (For example , helmet of executioner set)

Comment: Do you have any source? So unique is much stronger than legendary? Says who?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience of gameplay: legendary > unique. You see in special events they tell you to equip weapons of higher rarity as they are more powerful. I remember I had equipped a unique item and the game suggested equipping an epic or legendary item. So there it is.

Answer (score -1):

Eh, legendary feels better when it comes to events at least. I was playing the star of hope dream fight with my dragon lesson set and it said “you’ll fight more effectively in this battle if you equip items of MAXIMUM rarity”. So yeah, I think unique would be equal to epic or something like that.

Comment: The question is about rarity of items. This seems to be a comment.

Comment: No. This one actually gives proof. So you're saying you are using unique items and the game says y ou should include items of maximum rarity?